# /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root is full

Tags: kubuntu, disk-usage, development

I got "Low Disk Space" warning on my kubuntu 20.10 and could not figured it out why since I store everything on external HDs mounted on /media. The command df -h gave me the following :

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                       689M  3,5M  686M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root  115G  109G     0 100% /
tmpfs                       3,4G   40M  3,4G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                       4,0M     0  4,0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                   705M  121M  533M  19% /boot
/dev/sda1                   511M  7,8M  504M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                       689M   80K  689M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                       689M   60K  689M   1% /run/user/119
```

And I noticed /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root is 100% in use .. what is that ? How can I empty/fix it ?

Comment: `tree /media/`  please.

Comment: I get 
      -bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: Input/output error

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by reinstalled the OS. Got no support here and cant wait forever.